# Create windows script to traverse all subfolders of some folder, and delete a certain folder and all of it's contents if it exists

Tags: windows-7, script, batch-file, shell-script

here's the trick. Supposing I want to free up some space, and run that script in F:\UnrealProjects, which has a bit over 50-60 subfolders, I would like that script to traverse all of it's subfolders, check whether it contains a folder named `Binaries, Build, Intermediate` and delete everything in it including the `Binaries, Build, Intermediate` folder(s) itself it it exists.

I'm not quite lazy to do it manually once, but when reopening some projects, they do partially or fully rebuild themselves and that eats up space since I really don't need them fully built at all times. I just need to have them archived :) And build only the ones i do want to have built. I would really love to have this in script-form without (honestly speaking) having to write one myself and learn the best way to do it.

I know it's not very cool just blatantly asking for help/someone to make this script for me, but then again it's just a one-time thing.

Thanks for any help in advance guys (or gals), it's appreciated alot. If however someone has a better idea to retag this question, I'm all ears and very open to suggestions.

EDIT:

Ok, just to make things clear. I want to put this script in `U:\Projects`. I want to run it from `U:\Projects` and i want it to traverse all subfolders of the current `projects` folder (aka all projects), and delete `Build`, `Binaries`, and `Intermediate` folders if they exist in the currently-viewed project. I do not want to have to put this script in every project, and run it from there to just clear out three folders that may or may not exist.

I hope I have made it clearer now.

EDIT2: The point of this script is to merely 'clean' all intermediate, build and saved files from project folder, while keeping the rest intact so i can rebuild them later at some point.

Which means,
- for every folder in `U:\Unreal Projects`
   - delete `currentFolder\Build`, `currentFolder\Intermediate\,`currentFolder\Saved`,`currentFolder\Binaries`

and thats it :) thanks to everyone for trying to help out or contributing (y)

EDIT3:

Somehow, I turned to powershell. Here's what I got so far
`ls -Recurse -Include Build, Binaries, Intermediate, Saved | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse`
However, there are two problems with this.

Problem1 - i would really like it to not delete or include `Plugins\Binaries` or to somehow completely skip the Plugins folders. But that's not the biggest problem because....

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: I've solved it after witnessing many negative commentaries or downvotes. Yet, however, it won't let me accept my own answer until tomorrow so that gives everyone a chance to earn some upvotes or "useful comments" or simply improving my current PowerShell solution which does the job just fine IMO.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

for /F %%i in ('dir /b /a:d') do (
    dir /b /d %%i\build 2>NUL && echo rmdir /q /s %%i
)
```

Remove the echo before rmdir if you find that it does what you want? **WARNING** this is a bit untested so be careful maybe better to echo to a file and run from there after edit.

Comment: Does it work for Build, Binaries and Intermediate folders as well? How do I add two more folders in it? I see that it just tries with Build.

Comment: I'm sorry, i just tried it out and... it does find a few folders that contain a `Build` folder, but the echo output of the command is still `rmdir /q /s MyProject` which should be more like `rmdir /q /s MyProject/Build` no?

But having spotted the bug, i think i'll be able to fix it. Thanks for the help my man :)

Comment: no, sorry, it really doesn't work at all, it doesn't even go thru all of the subfolders of the `Projects` folder and detects every instance of `Build`, `Intermediate` or `Binaries` subfolders of every project.

Thanks for letting me know to run it in echo mode, because it would've really just wiped half of my workspace clean.

Comment: @shark You need to run it in the folder where you have subfolders, so it needs to run in **F:\UnrealProjects**. If not then you must change your question

Comment: @Shark do you mean you need to traverse sub sub folders too?

Comment: I have edited the question now, I hope I cleared it out. The script should really just "clean" the project while preserving the important project files :) It's a clean script that gets rid of the generated Binaries, Intermediate files, and Build 'release' version of it :)
EDIT: I have been running it from F:\UnrealProjects. However, It's also worth noting that there is a space in that folder name - `Unreal Projects`

Comment: Ok, wait, i have slightly edited it to -
`for /f "delims=" &&i in ('dir /a:d /s /b "Build"') do echo rd /s "%%i"`
and that one works okayish. It traverses all of my projects, and echoes a Build folder in it. In fact, it echoes a Build folder found in some of it's subfolders, like `MyProject\Intermediate\Build` which is close enough. I wouldn't like it to explore each project, just check for `Project\Build`, `Project\Intermediate` and `Project\Binaries` and delete those three (and their subfolders ofc) if they exist).

But it's slightly better now, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So, after a few unfortunate tries, here's what resolved the issue for me.

I made a `powershell-clean.bat` file, containing the following

```
echo 'this won't touch Binaries subfoldrs, only (Build, Intermediate, Saved).  
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "ls -Recurse -Include Build, Intermediate, Saved | rmdir -Force -Recurse"
```

I had to spare the `Binaries` folder, because when I put it in powerscript, it also nukes my `Project\Plugins\Binaries` which is a big no-no. On the other hand, I backed up the plugin and ran the script, and suddenly have 74.9GB instead of 546MB freespace.